# Implement async pattern over native call

Tags: c#

I would like to wrap the win32 DNS API `DnsQueryEx` function so that it can be used via the .NET TPL. I cannot use the managed methods in the `System.Net.Dns` namespace because they do not implement CNAME record lookup.

The only way that comes to mind is to poll the outcome of this operation periodically with non-blocking waits between polls using:

```
await Task.Delay(n)
```

The solution above seems inefficient. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: How doeshould DnsQueryEx normally notify it has a result? Can't you just call it from a Task.Run and await the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447188(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly states that:

> If a call to DnsQueryEx completes asynchronously, **the results of the
>   query are returned by the DNS_QUERY_COMPLETION_ROUTINE callback in
>   pQueryRequest**, the QueryStatus member of pQueryResults contains
>   DNS_REQUEST_PENDING, and DnsQueryEx returns DNS_REQUEST_PENDING.
>   Applications should track the pQueryResults structure that is passed
>   into DnsQueryEx until the DNS callback succeeds. Applications can
>   cancel an asynchronous query using the pCancelHandle handle returned
>   by DnsQueryEx.

Use [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) to implement Task based asynchronous method using `DNS_QUERY_COMPLETION_ROUTINE callback` in `pQueryRequest`